# Translating raster to ZMAP Plus Grid?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have been converting data published in is ESRI’s public ASCIIgrid format to ZMap Plus Grid in QGIS 2.18.6 .

When I tried to continue on my work, I suddenly received the following Error message:***ERROR 5: MINUSERPIXELVALUE must be specified.*** 
Even maps that I had already been converting the day before, could not be converted again!

One thing that struck my eye was, that in the Translate (Convert format) window the following text showed up: ***gdal_translate -of Leveller***
I am pretty certain, there was a ZMap in there before, instead of the Leveller. 
I have double- and triple-checked - I am using the correct output format (ZMap Plus Grid).

I am using 2.18.6, because in 3.4.4 the option to convert a map to ZMap Plus Grid seems to have disappeared.